# error: unreported exception ErrorException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Tags: java, exception, compiler-errors

Why this catch block is giving error at compile time, this code is used to wrap extra permission with jvtsession

```
public void cancelOperation() throws ErrorException {
    OCAClientUtil.checkIdleTimeout();
    if (!queryInProgress)
        return;
    String searchID = getSearchId();

    OCAClientAsset.resetIdleTimer();
    Security.runAs(asset.getSubject(), new PrivilegedAction(){
        public Object run(){
            try {
                jvtxsession.cancelQuery(searchID);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw OCAClientUtil.newErrorException(ex, "Cancel Query Work Order: ");
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
    queryInProgress = false;
}
```

why above mentioned error is coming

Comment: Did you carefully look at which line/method exactly the compilation error is referring? This is a quite self-explaining one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `run()` method in the callback of `Security.runAs()` does not declare `throws ErrorException`. Since the callback is not defined as throwing any checked exceptions, you cannot throw them in callback implementation.